# Idea for simple and good javascript gridview?

Tags: javascript, gridview

I need an easy to use javascript gridview.

The main feature why I don't use ASP.Net GridView is, that I must update it by javascript.

I google hundrets of them, but don't wanna test them all, so I like tot have good ideas from experience users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how easy you want it to be but have you tried jQuery plugin calld [jqGrid](http://trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) ??

Comment: Hey, I try it right now, but stuck in many things... jqGrid seems very complex and I don't thing I need it. I'm not sure about it.